# A simple expression that Mathematica can't simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm using Mathematica 9. I encountered an expression that Mathematica couldn't simplify to a simpler form:

```
Simplify[(Sqrt[a b] + Sqrt[a c])^4/a^2, {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}]
```

> ```
> (Sqrt[a b] + Sqrt[a c])^4/a^2
> ```

FullSimplify gives the same answer. However:

```
Simplify[(Sqrt[a b] + Sqrt[a c])^4/a^2-(Sqrt[b] + Sqrt[c])^4, {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

, as expected. So the simplification algorithm is imperfect? Imagine that a, b and c represent more complex expressions, is there a way to work around this problem?

**Edit**
I'll provide the original problem with more details. I have calculated a coefficient b1 to the following:

```
b1=(k-l)/(k+l)
```

where

```
k==Sqrt[2 m e]/h, l==Sqrt[2 m (e - V)]/h
```

m, e, h, k and l are real and positive (e > V)

I need to simplify the square of b1, which can be done easily by hand.

I try

```
Simplify[b1^2/.{k->Sqrt[2 m e]/h, l->Sqrt[2 m (e - V)]/h},{e > V > 0, m > 0, h > 0}]
```

The result is quite unpleasant:

$\frac{(\sqrt{m e} - \sqrt{m (e - V)})^2}{(\sqrt{m e} + \sqrt{m (e - V)})^2}$

So I decide to "help" Mathematica a bit:

```
Simplify[(k-l)^4/(k^2-l^2)^2/.{k->Sqrt[2 m e]/h, l->Sqrt[2 m (e - V)]/h},{e > V > 0, m > 0, h > 0}]
```

It returns

$\frac{(\sqrt{m e} - \sqrt{m (e - V)})^4}{m^2 V^2}$

This is the desired form. However, Mathematica refuses to take out and simplify the m factor. Even though Expand does get rid of m correctly, it won't help much because it creates a long messy expression that can't be simplified again to the compact unexpanded form.

Comment: Version 10 simplifies to `(Sqrt[b] + Sqrt[c])^4`

Comment: `FullSimplify[(Sqrt[a b]+Sqrt[a c])^4/a^2,a>0]` gives `(Sqrt[b]+Sqrt[c])^4`.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you could try `Expand` first and then `Simplify`.

```
Simplify[Expand[(Sqrt[a b] + Sqrt[a c])^4/a^2], a > 0]

(* (Sqrt[b] + Sqrt[c])^4 *)
```

Though admittedly this isn't my forte.

Worth noting is that with all of your assumptions it results in an expression with higher `LeafCount` than the original.

```
Simplify[Expand[(Sqrt[a b] + Sqrt[a c])^4/a^2], a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0]

(* b^2 + 6 b c + c^2 + 4 b Sqrt[b c] + 4 c Sqrt[b c] *)
```

Also of interest is that `FullSimplify` gives the same result as expanding with `Simplify` if `a > 0` is the only assumption provided.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing can be more simple. Let us do it. This is your starting expression:

```
 expr = (Sqrt[m*e] - Sqrt[m*(e - V)])^2/(Sqrt[m*e] + Sqrt[
    m*(e - V)])^2;
```

Here is a simplification function:

```
mySimp[expr_] := Simplify[expr, {m > 0, e > 0, V > 0}];
```

Now let us take the numerator and denominator of the expression:

```
 num1 = Numerator[expr];
den1 = Denominator[expr];
```

and multiply the both by the numerator:

```
 den2 = den1*num1 // mySimp

(*   m^2 V^2   *)

num2 = num1^2 // mySimp

(*   (Sqrt[e m] - Sqrt[m (e - V)])^4   *)
```

and finally construct the ratio again:

```
 expr2 = num2/den2

(*    (Sqrt[e m] - Sqrt[m (e - V)])^4/(m^2 V^2)   *)
```

Done. Have fun!